# Get value of package.json in gitLab CI YML

Tags: node.js, yaml, gitlab-ci, package.json

I'm using gitLab CI for my nodejs application. In my YML file I need to call a script to build a docker image. But instead of using `latest` I need to use the current version of the project.

This version value can be find in the `package.json` file of the repository.

Is it possible to read the version value of the package.json file to replace `latest` by the current version?

```
# ...
variables:
  CONTAINER_RELEASE_IMAGE: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest         # need version value instead of latest 

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    # ...
    - cd /opt/core/bundle && docker build -t $CONTAINER_RELEASE_IMAGE .
    - docker push $CONTAINER_RELEASE_IMAGE
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you are not against installing additional packages you can use `jq` which allows for much more flexibility (available in repository for both Ubuntu and Alpine).
Once you install it (for example `apt-get update && apt-get install -yqq jq` on Ubuntu):

```
- export VERSION=$(jq -r .version package.json)
- cd /opt/core/bundle && docker build -t $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$VERSION .
- docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$VERSION
```

Answer (score 59):

I would argue the easiest way to retrieve `version` from your `package.json` is to use node itself.

```yaml
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - export VERSION=$(node -p "require('./package.json').version")
    - export CONTAINER_RELEASE_IMAGE=$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$VERSION
    - cd /opt/core/bundle && docker build -t $CONTAINER_RELEASE_IMAGE .
    - docker push $CONTAINER_RELEASE_IMAGE
```

The `-p`/`--print` flag means evaluate the expression and print the result.  It's functionally equivalent to using the `-e`/`--eval=` flag and wrapping the expression in `console.log(...)`.

Comment: This worked perfectly. No need to install other packages or use other images or load extra files.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this should be the accepted answer since package.json related tasks come with `node` used here. Thanks for the tips it's that's so the natural way of things <3

Comment: This is the best answer. The version should be extracted by node as variable, not grep/awk/sed trickery.

Comment: if you get the error "node not found".  It means your build image doesn't have nodejs installed.    You can use my public build image      ```image: levarberry/node-kubectl```

Answer (score 11):

variables:

```
PACKAGE_VERSION: $(cat package.json | grep version | head -1 | awk -F= "{ print $2 }" | sed 's/[version:,\",]//g' | tr -d '[[:space:]]')  `
```

in your job or template

```
.package-template: &package_template 
image: docker-hub.registry.integ.fr.auchan.com/docker:latest
stage: package 
tags: 
  - stocks
script:
  - export VERSION= ``eval $PACKAGE_VERSION``
  - echo "======> Getting VERSION:  $VERSION" `
```

Answer (score 2):

You might not be able to do this purely in the `gitlab.yml` unfortunately, you could create a shell script as follows and check this into your source control

```
#!/bin/sh
args=("$@")
CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE=${args[0]}

PACKAGE_VERSION=$(cat package.json \
| grep version \
  | head -1 \
  | awk -F: '{ print $2 }' \
  | sed 's/[",]//g' \
  | tr -d '[[:space:]]')
CONTAINER_RELEASE_IMAGE=$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE\:$PACKAGE_VERSION
cd /opt/core/bundle && docker build -t $CONTAINER_RELEASE_IMAGE .
docker push $CONTAINER_RELEASE_IMAGE
```

Then execute this script with the argument of `$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE` in `gitlab.yml`

```
# ...
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    # ...
    - chmod +x script.sh
    - ./script.sh $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE
```

To the best of my knowledge this should work for you.

[Thank you to DarrenN and dbaba on Github for his package.json version extract shell function](https://gist.github.com/DarrenN/8c6a5b969481725a4413)

Comment: You also have to trim whitespaces: https://gist.github.com/DarrenN/8c6a5b969481725a4413#gistcomment-1678696

Answer (score 2):

You can use docker to get the package.json version. In this example we tag and push with "latest" and package.json version:

> *.gitlab-ci.yml*

```
docker-build-master:
  # Official docker image.
  image: docker:latest
  stage: build
  services:
    - docker:dind
  before_script:
    - docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGISTRY
  script:
    - export VERSION=$(docker run --rm -v "$PWD":/app:ro -w /app node:slim node -p "require('./package.json').version")
    - docker build --pull -t "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE" .
    - docker push "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest"
    - docker image tag "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest" "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$VERSION"
    - docker push "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$VERSION"
  only:
    - master
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use YAML anchor feature to set a variable that you can use in a job scripts.

```
.get_version: &get_version
  - "export SERVICE_VERSION=$(cat package.json | grep version | head -1 | awk -F: '{ print $2 }' | sed 's/[\",]//g' | tr -d '[[:space:]]')"
  - "Current version is: $SERVICE_VERSION"
```

and then somewhere in script part:

`.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
  variables:
    CONTAINER_NAME: myService
  script:
    - echo "My own script"
    - *get_version
    - docker build --iidfile imageid.txt --cache-from $CONTAINER_NAME:$SERVICE_VERSION -t $CONTAINER_NAME:$SERVICE_VERSION .
    - docker push $CONTAINER_NAME:$SERVICE_VERSION
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will be useful to others, I did this with a grep:

```bash
export PACKAGE_VERSION=$(grep -Po '(?<="version".{1} )"[0-9\.]+"' package.json | sed 's/\"//g')
```