# GitLab CI: How to pull specific docker container for deployment

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm doing the productive deploy in gitlab manually. I'm using docker container. 
Clicking on the 'Play'-Button in the pipeline list should do the deploy. 
But how do I get the version of the selected container? Doing this script is always trying to pull the `latest` version, which should not be. I want to pull the 'selected' container.

```
deploy_prod:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - docker pull $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE     # here selected version is missing
    # ...
  when: manual
  environment:
    name: productive
    url: https://example.com
  only:
    - master
```

Comment: What do you mean by selected?

Comment: In my pipeline list, there are multiple builds. As I do the deployment manually I have to select one of these builds (which is usually the latest) and click on the play-button. So exactly this build should be deployed. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: So you are building docker images in pipeline? Use exactly the same name as when you are building them.

Comment: Here you can see how I'm building those docker images: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43165840/get-value-of-package-json-in-gitlab-ci-yml/43299217#43299217 And because of that version values there is the problem to pull a specific build

Comment: Well, just do it the same way. In fact that script is overcomplicated and I'd just use jq to pull the version into a variable. Of course that has the overhead of pulling the entire repository just to know the name of the image.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean... What is 'jq'?

Comment: More info on jq here: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments to your question, simply use the same script you used to push the image, to pull it in the deploy stage.

Here's an example `pull.sh` script:

```
#!/bin/sh
args=("$@")
CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE=${args[0]}

PACKAGE_VERSION=$(cat package.json \
| grep version \
  | head -1 \
  | awk -F: '{ print $2 }' \
  | sed 's/[",]//g' \
  | tr -d '[[:space:]]')
CONTAINER_RELEASE_IMAGE=$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE\:$PACKAGE_VERSION
docker pull $CONTAINER_RELEASE_IMAGE
```

Notice the `pull` instead of the `push` in the last line.

Then modify your deploy job like this:

```
deploy_prod:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - ./pull.sh $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE
    # ...
  when: manual
  environment:
    name: productive
    url: https://example.com
  only:
    - master
```